# Dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Samsung NP300EC5 running Windows 8.1 after disabling "Secure Boot"

After installation no Windows items appeared in grub menu.

I ran BootRepair, that told me "everything OK".

After reboot no way to run Windows: all Windows items execute Windows repair without success.

Output of Boot Repair at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6342469/

Any suggestion?